# Client redirect compatibility?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am wanting to use something like this:

```
alert("foo");
window.location.href="foo.php";
```

Is this okay to be using on a site that will see people using all the main browsers? (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera etc)

I need it to be compatible. I cannot use PHP headers for my redirects as I need to be able to display an alert(); before redirecting.

Also, is this a fast method of redirection? If not, any other options that still allow me to display an alert and wait for them to click ok BEFORE redirecting?

Thank for your input.

Comment: If you must do an `alert()` (which is pretty obnoxious), then this would be the way to go; except for those without JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be just use a link or use the [meta refresh tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm). Those are going to be a lot more stable and cross browser compatible ;)

Comment: Apparently user must acknowledge a message before redirection, so meta refresh is not going to work here

Comment: Yeah, it's almost like an error message that is shown to the user before they are redirected. Maybe it would just be smarter to pass an error code to an error page and display the error? Then a link for redirection? It just seems fiddly and my windows.location.href is working well.